# How to put objects from an array as parameters for a method while parsing the array?

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

I am new to Java and programming in general. I am currently facing the following problem:

I have an array of 5 objects. 2 of those 5 objects have a certain property and I want to send those 2 objects as parameters for a method. Is there any possibility that, after parsing the array for items with that property, to put those items as parameters to the function without copying them to auxiliary variables?

Comment: If you find the indexes (`i` and `j`) of the two objects you want, you can call your method and pass it `(arr[i], arr[j])` without assigning instances of your array anywhere outside it. But there's no problem with assigning objects to multiple variables; it doesn't copy them. Just makes a new reference to the same object.

Comment: You should add some code, such as what the array looks like, what the method signature looks like, and how you are parsing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know how many objects are going to meet your criteria, you wouldn't know how many need to be passed into a new function. So, I would recommend that your function (if it doesn't already) accepts an ArrayList.

What you can do is loop through your array to find items that meet your criteria, and then add them to an ArrayList. When you are done, you can pass that array list to your function. Here is a code snippet, that assumes your array is String variables:

```
ArrayList<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++){
   if(myArray[i].contains("Something."){ // Use whatever criteria you need here.
      tmpList.Add(myArray[i]);
   }
}

myFunction(tmpList);
```

I think this is the best approach. ArrayLists are unbounded, so you can add an unknown amount of items to it.

For example, you said in your question you have an array of 5 items, and 2 of them may need to be passed into the function. If that was always the case, you could define an array of length 2 that stores these items, or you could design your function to have 2 inputs.

But what happens when you need to pass 3 items? Your function might not be designed to accept 3 items. Or, you've already defined an array as length 2, so you can't give it this third item. If you use an ArrayList you will have this flexibility moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then no you can't do this, but *you shouldn't want to*.

"Copying" them to other variables is the correct thing to do, but your terminology is wrong. You can create two variable `references` which point to these two specific objects that have the property you want, then pass these references in to the method. This does not copy any content of your objects, it just creates a named `reference` which points to the same instance.

Alternatively, you can consider passing in the entire array into the method and having the method determine which objects it will use from the array, but this is a design decision that should have a strong foundation if you will make it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the size of an array and the number of objects to pick up is unknown at compile time, otherwise you would just be able to declare a function with 2 parameters and call it as usual. 
So the answer is "no", you'll have to use another array or, easier, a java List:

```
List<MyObj> pickedOnes = new ArrayList<MyObj>(yourArray.length); //create an array-backed list
for (MyObj obj: yourArray) {
    if (isToPick(obj)) {//checking your condition on whether to pick up the object
         pickedOnes.add(obj);
    }
}
yourFunction(pickedOnes); //call it with List<MyObj>
```

Note that Java does not actually copy MyObj objects, it only copies references to it, which is very fast and whose cost is negligible.